# img title attribute displaying blocks instead of foreign characters

Tags: html

A few of the images on my website have a `title` attribute containing foreign characters.

These characters display correctly on the rest of the website, and in the HTML source, but appear incorrectly on the little browser title-hover.

**Hover-over**

[image: Title problem]

**Elsewhere**

[image: Displayed correctly]

**Source**

```
<img width="288" height="145" src="http://www.xxxxxxxx.com/dev/wp-content/uploads/2012/03/Betta-patoti-7-288x145.jpg" class="attachment-species-thumb" alt="???~" title="© ???~">
```

Is there anything that can be done about this?

---

**EDIT**

The following code is on every page on my site:

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />`

---

Thanks in advance,

Comment: This tend to mean that the character set you are using is not installed on the client computer. If this is a Unicode encoding, it is possible that the character range is not installed.

Comment: Thanks Oded. I've tried it on 6 machines now, all with the same results. Also, why would the characters be visible on the page itself, but not on the `title` hover?

Comment: That's not what I see in your pasted source. Can you confirm that you are seeing the correct characters in source and rendered normally? Please also explain what browser/OS combos you have been testing on that have this result.

Comment: Oh *duhhhh* I really should've checked the source before I copied and pasted it :( I'll update the source now - with a screenshot - as it does display correctly in the source.

Comment: And, as you say that, I've just tested it on my new PC - and they're working correctly. Would you like to post that as an answer? Must be machine-dependent indeed; this is running Win 7 (SP1) with Chrome latest where the others were XP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue tends to mean that the character set you are using is not installed on the client computer.

If this is a Unicode encoding, it is possible that the character range is not installed on the client computer (in order to save space, many Windows installation only include a subset of the fonts, normally excluding far east fonts and those less used in the west).

Answer (score 1):

The rendering of `title` attribute values is browser-dependent and normally uses a specific font, which is settable by the user (though extremely few users know about this) and naturally varies by browser and platform. In some modern settings, browsers are able to use different fonts here, but on older systems, you get something different, quite possibly often boxes indicating characters not present in the font. There is nothing you can do about this as an author, when using the `title` attribute.

The morale is that nothing essential (if anything) should be communicated in `title` attributes.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the answer by @oded I found that changing the `QuickInfo` font in `Windows XP` from `Tahoma` to `Lucida Sans Unicode` traded in the ugly boxes for the actual unicode characters I wanted to see.

[image]