# why doesnt the Browser view element title tag in the correct format?

Tags: html, xhtml

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [img title attribute displaying blocks instead of foreign characters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10339146/img-title-attribute-displaying-blocks-instead-of-foreign-characters)

Im working on a case where I have to set the tooltips on elements to show up in chinese. I have set the page XHTML Language attribute to zh-CN and the element title tags accordingly as below:

```
<div class="cleditorButton" title="字体颜色" style="background-color: transparent; background-position: -216px 50%; "></div>
```

but the titles are not viewed in the correct format when I hover over them.

[image]

Is this because I do not have the chinese fonts installed on my pc?

Comment: can you see it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/bVL3r/)?

Comment: *"Is this because I do not have the chinese fonts installed on my pc?"* - Most likely. Have you tried installing an Asian font?

Comment: No, I cant, I have a feeling its because I deleted the chinese fonts off of my pc a while back. If thats the case then its great news.

Answer (score 1):

Set the charset to utf-8, it would be something like this in your meta.

```
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer [this site](http://www.kavoir.com/2009/01/what-are-the-chinese-or-mandarin-web-safe-fonts.html) for more ellaborate answer

This will explain the browser view element